# Threading: How can I solve this without too much code?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

The main purpose is to make multiple threads basing on count of pages. **Is** there any way to make it easier than just making ton of `if`s? Cannot get an idea of how to solve this properly.

```
import threading

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import system, name
import requests
import sqlite3
import time
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import pprint
from threading import Thread


def page_check(URL):
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'category-products'}).findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'products-grid'})
    print(products)

def page_start(count):
    count = str(count)
    URL = 'html/page/' + count + '/ke'
    threading.Thread(target=page_check(URL)).start()

def number_of_pages():
    URL = 'html/page/'
    sites = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sites.text, 'html.parser')
    number = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'amount mobilehidden'}).text
    number = number.split()
    number = int(number[5])
    pages1 = number / 48
    pages2 = int(number / 48)
    if (pages1 / pages2) > 1:
        pages = pages2 + 1
    elif (pages1 / pages2) == 1:
        pages = pages2
    return pages

def main():
    pages = number_of_pages()

    if pages == 1:
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/1/limit/48.html')).start()
    if pages == 2:
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/1/limit/48.html')).start()
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/2/limit/48.html')).start()
    if pages == 3:
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/1/limit/48.html')).start()
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/2/limit/48.html')).start()
        threading.Thread(target=page_check('htmlpage/p/3/limit/48.html')).start()

    main()
```

Comment: What is the problem with the above code ?

Comment: It has too many ifs, I want to make it like, if I have 18 pages it will make 18 threads

Comment: An even more fundamental issue is that you're not creating threads correctly — the way the `target=` argument to `threading.Thread()` is being specified causes the target function is be called before the thread is even created (and `page_check()` effectively returns `None`, so that will be the value assigned to the `target` argument).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) method.

```
num_pages = 3
for i in range(num_pages):
    page_start(i)
# 0
# 1
# 2
```

range() will provide an iterable of values counting from 0 up to (but not including) the target number. You can also provide a starting value, eg, range(1, 4) will count 1, 2, 3. See the docs for more options.

Edit: This just addressed how to avoid multiple `if` statements. To start multiple threads, use pythons concurrency modules: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor

Comment: Tested it already, it just starts one thread, when it ends this thread it starts next one

Comment: Even my option with page_start deffinition doesn't work, I need to put all threads inside of the main function

Comment: Sorry, I only really addressed the issue with avoiding multiple `if` statements. If you want to start multiple threads, you should use pythons concurrency modules. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 0):

Added this code to main and I will just exec it. Thanks to everyone

```
code = ''
while pages > 0:
    count = str(count)
    URL = 'htmlpage' + count + '/limit/48.html'
    code = code + 'threading.Thread(target=page_check(' + "'" +  URL + "'" + ')).start()' + '\n'
    pages = pages - 1
    count = int(count)
    count = count + 1
```